# Ember.js binding to component/view style attributes

Tags: css, ember.js, ember.js-view

I'm trying to create a component, or a view if that is better suited for this, that binds to given model's computed properties and changes style attributes accordingly. I'm using Ember App Kit if that affects in anyway how this should be done.

The component would be a a meter that has 2 computed properties to bind to: "limitDeg", "currentValueDeg". Every model instance that will use this component can supply those as model computed properties to the component.

The meter has 3 overlapping divs - ".meter-div" being just background with no bindings, and one of which will be rotated with CSS3 transform by X-degrees to show the current "limitDeg". So adjusting the "transform: rotate(###deg);" is the key here. There is a "indicator-div", that is simple indicator that similarly rotates based on the "currentValueDeg" with CSS3 animation loop.

Below is a basic rough outline of how I've thought of having the component/view:

```
<div class="my-component-container">
    <div class="limit-div"></div>
    <div class="meter-div"></div>
    <div class="indicator-div"></div>
</div>
```

...and I would use it like this for example:
   {{#each}}
   ...
       {{my-component}}
   ...
   {{/each}}

1) I would like the component to bind to the model so, that when the "limitDeg" computed property changes, the ".limit-div" will be rotated by X-degrees with CSS3 transform: rotate(###degrees);.

2) I would like animate the ".indicator-div" with a CSS3 animation that loops infinitely, binding to the currentValueDeg computedProperty.

Is this something I should even try do this with one component/view, or rather do it this multiple components/views inside one partial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using handlebars, just wrap your component in tags that specify it as such:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='components/component_name'>
  <div class="limit-div"></div>
  <div class="meter-div"></div>
  <div class="indicator-div"></div>
</script>
```

Then include it in your view like this:

```
{{component_name objectToPassIn=this classNames='my-component-container' tagName='div'}}
```

If you wanted the component to display a model property, you could do something like this inside the component (using the variables in my example above):

```
<span class='property-wrapper'>
  {{objectToPassIn.objectProperty}}
</span>
```

Edit:

For the sake of clarity, `objectToPassIn` is the model that is passed to the view that calls the component.

Comment: I still need a way to bind to the style attribute and change that when the values for limitValueDeg and currentValueDeg.

    <div class="limit-div" style="transform: rotate(limitValueDeg deg);"></div>

Can I get those values bound to the objectToPassIn ?

Comment: Well I guess you could bind those as a string attribute on the object and then use the handlebars `bind-attr` method like this `{{bind-attr attr='objectProperty'}}` to change the value and look at the front end. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to bind to style. When I tried this, ember.js and handlebars wrap the element with metamorphs and breaks the tag - style doesn't render properly.

Comment: Hm, that seems strange, not had any problems with `bind-attr` myself. In that case have you tried in the controller using jQuery and the `.css()` method to achieve the same thing using the object property? The only thing I can think is somehow the browser wasn't able to parse the binding. Could it be that it's a string literal without a semi-colon or something so it's not seen as valid CSS?

Comment: Actually what you proposed earlier worked, I think I tried to use style="bindableAttribute" earlier, and not bind-attr style="bindableAttribute".

I got this working thanks to you :-)